# How to create a solr query that searches by multiple keywords in all fields

Tags: solr

I want to perform a solr query on all fields for multiple keywords. For example, I want to search for the word "dog" AND the word "cat".

So far, I've tried to do something like this:

```
q=dog cat
```

or something like:

```
q=dog,cat
```

However, I think my queries are actually doing an OR instead of an AND.

Comment: If you want to search on and combination then you can find on this link https://programinghacksandtricks.blogspot.in/2018/01/multiple-word-search-in-solr.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the default operator (AND/OR) and you want to search in "all fields".

For most parsers you can use the parameter `q.op` to change the default parser (e.g. for the [Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) and the [DisMax Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm(MinimumShouldMatch)Parameter)) or you can use the defaultOperator in [schema.xml](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator) or [Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API#SchemaAPI-GettheDefaultQueryOperator).

Be aware that you will search only in the `default field`.

If you want to search in "all fields" you have to [copy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) all your fields to one field (and use this as default field) or you have to list all your fields in the DisMax [qf-parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf(QueryFields)Parameter).
The results will not be the same: In the second case your "AND"-Search must match one of the fields (with its special tokenizer), in the first each term could be in different fields to match (because in the end all terms are in the default field).